# Permission denied when moving folder that I didnt create, in samba server, mounted with cifs

Tags: 20.04, permissions, samba, cifs

In a samba's shared folder, I don't have permissions, as a client, to either move a file I didn't create or to create things inside of it, even as sudo.

Command used to mount the samba server :

```
sudo mount -t cifs //10.0.0.100/share asd -o user=lubuntu,username=lubuntu,password=1234567,uid=999,gid=999,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,mfsymlinks
```

But I have permission to :

1. Create and modify anything I created in the shared folder.
2. Modify, rename and move every file that other client besides me
   creates.
3. rename folders that others clients created

I tried :

1. `sudo chmod 777 folder`
2. `sudo chown lubuntu:lubuntu folder`
3. `sudo umount -l folder` (and then mount again)

Nothing works, I keep getting permission denied when trying to create thing inside the folder or to move it, even as sudo.

Comment: What is the name of the folder you are trying to remove?

Comment: @David, in the question i called it 'folder', but in the reality were many folders, with diferent names (only letters), some created as sudo, and some not. As long i'm not the creator, the result is the same.

Comment: Is the [sticky bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit) of folder set? To see it `ls -ld folder/` - To unset: `chmod -t folder/`.

Comment: @Marc Vanhoomissen  The first command returns : drwxrwxrwx 2 lubuntu lubuntu 0 dez 30 12:46 comsudo2/ 
And after the second command, nothing changes. Still no permission to move it.